# How to recurse a tree and create an array of parent path nodes?

Tags: javascript

I have a tree that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "B",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "C",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "D"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "E"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "F"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "G",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "H"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to walk through my tree and, for each node, add the path information for the parent components. So, using my example above, I am looking for how to generate this:

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "path": [
        "A"
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "B",
            "path": [
                "A",
                "B"
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "C",
                    "path": [
                        "A",
                        "B",
                        "C"
                    ],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "D",
                            "path": [
                                "A",
                                "B",
                                "C",
                                "D"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "E",
                            "path": [
                                "A",
                                "B",
                                "C",
                                "E"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "F",
                    "path": [
                        "A",
                        "B",
                        "F"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "G",
            "path": [
                "A",
                "G"
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "H",
                    "path": [
                        "A",
                        "G",
                        "H"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) will be sufficient.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/243705

Comment: Think recursively. How can you make sure that each child retrieves the path of the parent plus itself?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is not homework. I've tried various implementations using a while loop to try and traverse through the tree, but I can't quite get the output correct.

Comment: This is something better handled with [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is small recursive iterative proposal of setting the path which exploits `this`.

Source:

- [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> `The bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

- [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), thisArg parameter:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value. Otherwise, the value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) will be passed for use as its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according [to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
function setPath(o) {
    o.path = this.concat(o.name);
    Array.isArray(o.children) && o.children.forEach(setPath, o.path);
};

var object = { "name": "A", "children": [{ "name": "B", "children": [{ "name": "C", "children": [{ "name": "D" }, { "name": "E" }] }, { "name": "F" }] }, { "name": "G", "children": [{ "name": "H" }] }] };

setPath.bind([])(object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I was just trying to understand the general approach of how one might solve this type of problem. Your solution is incredibly terse. I'm definitely going to need to read a bit to understand how it works. Cheers.

Comment: @turtle, you are welcome. please see edit for some more information.